# Operator overloading behavior based on member

Tags: c++, templates

```
Struct A
    {
        int* ptr;
        int operator+=(const A& other)
        { 
            // if(ptr == nullptr)
            // { DoSomething(); } 
            // else { ...}
        }

      ...
     }
```

Is it possible to have a template operator+= (on a NON-template `Class A`) in order to resolve that if statement at compile time?

EDIT: I have a bunch of API's, all with the signature:

```
A funcX()
{
    // lot of A's overloaded operators calls

    return A;
}
```

Now, I need to use those API's with a new type, that shares a lot of members with `A` and add a new one (a smart pointer).

Since all the `A funcX()` return by value, I cannot derive my new type from `A` and call `A funcX()` with the derived type (slicing).
So my solution is to add a smart pointer to `A`, and a constructor in `A` that initializes that pointer.

So now I get to use all the API's, and when `A` is constructed with its new constructor (that initializes the pointer), I want all the operators to have a different behaviour than the existing one.

I was looking into some templates tricks to avoid the cost of checking the pointer inside each operator, although from the comments it doesn't seem possible to achieve it.

Comment: No. Why do you need it to?

Comment: How could data that is available only at runtime be used at compile-time?

Comment: Probably. I'm not sure I follow. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @PasserBy allow me to explain myself better

Comment: Please elaborate on `//lot of A's overloaded operators calls` with some real example. Eg: `a+a`..etc. so we know the real context.

Comment: Also, how does compiler know that `ptr` is `nullptr` at compile time when it might be altered in runtime? Also I believe there should be a `DerivedFromA` struct in this context so you ask this question.

Comment: I think you might want a static analyzer like [Infer](https://fbinfer.com/) from Meta.

Comment: `I was looking into some templates tricks to avoid the cost of checking the pointer inside each operator` - This is where you seem to be doing astray. The cost of checking for a null pointer with a switch statement is trivial.

Comment: My psychic powers suggest you really want to derive a class from `A` and have the `operator +=` overload call a virtual method.